# не все классы отрабатываются в питоне и закрывается процесс

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы автозакрытия браузера. Достал по сути чужой код для своего задания по автоматизации работы с сайтом написанный на **питоне** с **селениумом**.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui


class SBMS_start():   #подключение к сервису или сайту
    def open_service(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver.get("некая ссылка")
        time.sleep(1)
    
    def auth(self):    #авторизация
        driver = self.driver
        time.sleep(1)
        username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("user")
        username_textbox.send_keys("логин")
        time.sleep(1)
        password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        password.send_keys("пароль")
        time.sleep(1)
        button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSW_WORKFRAMES_CONTAINER"]/div/div/div/div[5]/button')
        button1.click() #ENTER
```

после чего браузер закрывается, но у меня есть второй класс который по сути должен проработать после данного класса.

Вот второй класс который не срабатывает из за закрытия браузера:

```
class search_client(SBMS_start):
    def search_by(self):
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 1.5
        pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True 

        pyautogui.size()
        pyautogui.position()

        pyautogui.moveTo(370,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(370,190,duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.write("777772194")    #input of msisdn


checkbox = SBMS_start()
checkbox.open_service()
checkbox.auth()

checkbox = search_client()
checkbox.search_by(777772194)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `checkbox = SBMS_start()` на `checkbox = search_client()`. search_client потомок класса sbms_start, и обладает всеми его методами. & У вас не закрывался браузер, у вас программа штатно завершала свою работу, а второй класс попросту нигде не вызывался.

Comment: сработало, спасибо